# Advantage of Internal Procedures Forward Declarations in PL/SQL Packages

Tags: oracle, plsql

Say I have the Package below (please take note of the comments):

```
Create or replace package test_package_fdec as

    procedure ext_proc1;
    procedure ext_proc2;

end test_package_fdec;
/

Create or replace package body test_package_fdec as

    procedure int_proc; -- forward declaration

    procedure int_proc2 -- explicit internal procedure declaration
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('this is int_proc2');

    end int_proc2;

    procedure ext_proc1
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to StackOverflow');
        dbms_output.put_line('i will use an internal procedures with Forward Declarations');
        int_proc;

    end ext_proc1;

    procedure ext_proc2
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to Oracle Forums');
        dbms_output.put_line('i will use an internal procedures without Forward Declarations');
        int_proc2;

    end ext_proc2;

    procedure int_proc
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('used forward declaration');

    end int_proc;

end test_package_fdec;
```

What is the Advantage/Disadvantage of using Forward Declaration in Internal Package Body Procedures?
Does it have impact in Performance?
In the same vein, are there any Advantage/Disadvantage in explicitly writing the internal procedure in the Declaration Section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward declarations are not related to performance.  They only exist for those rare cases where a procedure is called before it is declared.

The only time this is absolutely necessary is when two subprograms reference each other, like this:

```
Create or replace package body test_package_fdec as

    procedure int_proc; -- forward declaration

    procedure int_proc2
    is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('this is int_proc2');
        int_proc;
    end int_proc2;

    procedure int_proc
    is
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('this is int_proc2');
        int_proc2;
    end int_proc;
end test_package_fdec;
/
```

Sometimes forward declarations are useful for cosmetic reasons.  It's important to list code in the order that makes sense to you, not necessarily the order in which it is called.  Adding a forward declaration can help you keep the code in a more logical order.

The only downside to forward declarations is that some IDEs will not handle them properly.  This can cause the object browser to get confused, and clicking on an object may take you to the forward declaration instead of the full code definition.

Comment: Is it best practice to use forward declarations like in my post `int_proc`? or just explicitly define the internal procedure like `int_proc2`? thank you!

Comment: It's only a best practice if there's a good reason to do it.  It's hard to say if it matters in your example because the names are examples and don't mean much.  If your package is just a bunch of code thrown together, than just re-order the procedures so you won't need forward declarations.  But if you strive to make your procedures like chapters in a book, then the order may be important and you may need to use forward declarations to support a logical order.